# Event ID 9646 What is a Folder View Object and how is it used by Outlook/Exchange in the MAPI session?

Tags: exchange, outlook

Error is: *Mapi session (UserMAPI session LegacyDN ID) with client type MoMT exceeded the maximum of 500 objects of type FolderView.*

Current setup: Outlook 365 Pro Plus client and Exchange server 2013 CU6 on-premise houses the mailboxes

I am trying to find out what the folder view object is and how it is used, this error is only appearing for one user reporting freezing when he goes to edit calendar items. He has other glitchy behaviour as well which I am still trying to troubleshoot but so far the most obvious is the event error being recorded.

I have increased the counts via the registry fix as suggested by many sites and blogs, but I still want to know what the Folder Object view is and why he is reaching the max in the first place. Last count I did he had a total of 376 folder (he has full control to multiple mailboxes). Can anyone elaborate or know of a site that explains what a folder view is and how a user can reach the maximum?

Thanks

Shal

Answer (score 0):

The Folder Object View does relate to how many folders an Outlook user in cached mode has. The default value is 500 but what a lot of people forget is that the total also includes shared mailboxes and public folder favourites. From [Outlook 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/kb/982697) on you can put the shared mailboxes in online mode and it won't count towards the 500 folder total.

Comment: All mailboxes are of the user mailboxes not shared mailboxes types due to an old legacy application which has just been removed this week. All are in online mode only there is no caching.

According to Technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477612(v=exchg.141).aspx there is the open item limit for Folder and Folder View. The user isn't reaching the limit for Folders (objtFolder) only Folder View (objtFolderView). Plus he isn't clicking on any extra mailbox folder just his own mailbox and this error is occuring.

Comment: I've asked on a Microsoft forum previously what the difference between objtfolder and objtfolderview is but didn't get a proper answer. From previous troubleshooting they seem to be essentially the same and most fixes mention changing both values. Have you gone to the users computer to confirm it is in online mode and that there is only one profile? No ost file present?

Comment: Yes the user is in online mode, I control this via Group Policy. We did think it was that to begin with (due to an old config before I forced everyone to be online mode only), but his SSD died and so we rebuilt has profile. So the .ost file is not present but the issue continues to happen. He mentioned it appears to coincide with his attempts to edit a recurring meeting so I wonder if the editing of the meeting generates multiple views. I am seeking his permission to login to his account since he is on holiday (he is an executive), hopefully I can work at how it happens and go from there.

Comment: Sounds like the best idea, try and recreate the problem.

Comment: Ok, so I removed all extra mailboxes from his account and I still get the same error logged in the event viewer. He did have a folder in the inbox with a lot of items in it so I moved this outside of the Inbox. Still no idea when Exchange decides to generate a FolderView object.

Comment: Think I was wrong about this being only for cached client, will update the answer. Maybe the user has under 500 folders but keeps having to open new mapi sessions because of a network issue? You can check on connections using ExMon - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51101